# Organizing Objective-C source files

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, clojure

In Java we organize files in packages, Clojure has namespaces and Ruby has modules.
How to organize Objective-C files? any convention/best practice exists?

In Xcode everything is going under "classes" directory.

Answer (score 2):

1. What I usually do is enforce physical folders (and groups within Xcode) for the files and have them added to the project from where they are. From there you can group files logically however you want them.
   By default, it will create the file within the same Classes folder, and I find it difficult to navigate when dealing with an external source control client.
2. Leverage Categories to have separate files for separate logic for a particular class. For example I will have private method interface in the implementation file with a separate category name so that it is somewhat "private" to other implementations.
3. For uniqueness, you could try to prefix folders or groups of classes.

Comment: Consider #import <UIKit/UIKit.h> , does this mean that UIKit.h is under UIKit directory?  Does this mean that I can create a directory named "Controllers" (for example) under "Classes" directory?

Comment: Yes you can. For example, you can #import "ViewControllers/SampleController.h" for a folder named ViewControllers

Answer (score 0):

We use MVC on all but the smallest projects.  So in the "Classes" folder we start by adding three folders, Model, View, and Controller.  Under those directories we might create subfolders grouped by functionality with the app (controllers for various subsections, etc.).  You can add files directly to Xcode or the folders themselves.  Similarly we have a Resources directory, usually in the same directory as the .xcodeproj file and under that folders for Images, Nibs, Audio, etc.

Of course the above just describes a disk-based organization strategy.  Since Objective-C is still C, you can build libraries and header files for APIs that you want to export.  You can also use categories.  Many of our projects reference a /Common directory that is outside of the project folder (and under Common we have Model, View, Controller, etc.).  Sometimes we copy files from Common into the project if we expect to make significant changes to them that we don't want other projects to inherit.

Answer (score 0):

I just organize things in XCode. Group files as appropriate. Yes, everything ends up in the Classes directory.